# How do I recreate this overlay/design in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

How do I recreate this color overlay/design in photoshop? Colour overlay/wash and a triangle grid

[image]

it's the main image on our website http://www.advantawealth.co.uk/

Comment: http://www.advantawealth.co.uk/ its the main image of my website - trying to build new images in the same technique

Answer (score 14):

Create a pattern using this module:

[image: module]

Over the main image, make a layer and fill it with the pattern

[image: pattern]

Invert the pattern layer

[image: pattern layer]

Change the blend mode to Screen and reduce the opacity

[image: Screen mode]

Make a **Layer Mask** using a gradient from black to white from left to right

[image: Layer Mask]

Result

[image: end]

Comment: And seeing as the slight gradient of the colour overlay is dead vertical in axis, and fades from the darker sepia-type tone towards white... could be done most easily with a Layer Effect Gradient Overlay.

Answer (score 10):

I'm just *adding to* Danielillo's already-excellent answer, and with one variant from his approach - but it's still basically the same thinking - that's why I stole his image so *brazenly*! What I'm doing differently is working from default stuff wherever possible, so you're not creating much new at all, and I'm leaving everything easily re-editable - working non-destructively.

Starting point
[image]

Create a new pattern fill layer - **Layer>New Fill Layer>Pattern** - pick the diagonal lines pattern which is first up in the chooser:

[image]

Create another new pattern fill layer - **Layer>New Fill Layer>Pattern** - but this time select the right-angled one in the pattern chooser

[image]

Here's what the diagonal lines pattern fill looks like:
[image]

Now, just so you can see where we're headed here, switch the transparency blending mode of both pattern fills to Multiply - you'll see this:

[image]

We're not actually going to keep it this way, but it should be giving you the idea we're headed for...

Now, turn off your actual image layer for now (using the eyeball symbol), then select the two pattern fill layers in the layers palette, and right-click, and pull down till you get to Merge Layers:

[image]

Then you select the resulting merged layer, and down at the bottom of the layers palette you click on the adjustment layer button (looks like a circle, half-white, half-black) and choose invert - you'll now see your triangulated grid in white on black like so:

[image]

Select the adjustment layer and the grids layer and again, right-click merge layers, and then I name the new one "Grid" so I know exactly what it is. Select that "Grid" layer, and change its opacity blend mode to lighten - you should see this:

[image]

With that Grid Layer selected, go up to the menubar and go to **Layer>Layer Mask>Reveal All** like so:

[image]

Left-click once into the resulting Layer mask you'll see in the layers palette, then choose your gradient tool:

[image]

Pull down on the gradient selector to get to a straight black and white gradient, and adjust it to your liking - this gradient is how we control that layer mask to fade its effect out towards the right-hand side:

[image]

Now turn on your image again, and select that layer, and click at the bottom of the layers palette on the "FX" button, and choose **Gradient Overlay**:

[image]

Make sure your gradient angle is either 90 or -90, and adjust to your liking:

[image]

And... Bob's yer uncle!

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I adding a medal :-)